# How does Docker and AWS ECS Service interact?

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

i'm new to amazon web services, and im involved in project where we dicided to user serverless architecture which consist of lambda(nodejs), dynamo DB, cognito etc, as a DevOps engineer, im trying to figure out how to to do **CD/CD** for the project.

I've read multiple articles, they mentioning fargate and other services which i understand, but when it comes to docker and ECS im bit confused, *

*i dont know if we push the image to ECS and write the dockerfile so that my lambda functions can run, or we just push the image to ECS so that the cluster of lambda functions can run?*

- **please anyone with a clear explanantion please assist.**

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> i dont know if we push the image to ECS and write the dockerfile so
>   that my lambda functions can run, or we just push the image to ECS so
>   that the cluster of lambda functions can run?

You push Docker images to AWS Elastic Container Registry (ECR). ECS can then pull those images to deploy docker containers in either EC2 or Fargate.

ECS, ECR and Docker are totally unrelated to AWS Lambda. You don't run docker containers in AWS Lambda.

Answer (score -1):

Implemented similar using Jenkins.. We have create docker image using jenkins as part of CI CD pipeline.. then we store those docker images in ECR. In ECS we create task definition and container instance, then container instance will refer to the ECR images which we created as part of CICD.

Dokcerfile was part of docker image.